# Why do i have a problem rendering this 'Loading' component in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props, conditional-rendering

I have 2 components which use the same data which I am fetching from a json-server.
One component uses the data as shown below:

```
function Home(props) {
return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='row align-items-start'>
            <div className='col-12 col-md m-1'>
                <RenderCard item={props.dish}
                    isLoading={props.dishesLoading}
                    errMess={props.dishErrMess} />
            </div>
            <div className='col-12 col-md m-1'>
                <RenderCard item={props.promotion}
                    isLoading={props.promoLoading}
                    errMess={props.promoErrMess} />
            </div>
            <div className='col-12 col-md m-1'>
                <RenderCard item={props.leader}
                    isLoading={props.leaderLoading}
                    errMess={props.leaderErrMess} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);}
```

The other component uses the data as shown below:

```
const leaders = props.leaders.map((leader) => {
    return (
        <RenderLeader leader={leader} isLoading={props.isLoading}
            errMess={props.errMess} />
    );
});
```

Both the RenderLeader and RenderCard components have a similar structure with an if-else loop to display loading animation or error messages along with the actual content.

```
function RenderLeader({ leader, isLoading, errMess }) {
if (isLoading) {
    return (
        <Loading />
    );
}
else if (errMess) {
    return (
        <h4>{errMess}</h4>
    );
}
else
    return (CONTENT)
```

The problem is that the loading animation and the error message are being displayed for the Home component but NOT for the other component which has exactly similar structure. Moreover, the data is being actually fetched for the second component, its just that it wont display the loading animation and error messages. What is wrong with this ?
**Edit**
This is how i invoke them both:

```
<Home
                dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]}
                dishesLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
                dishErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
                promotion={this.props.promotions.promotions.filter((promo) => promo.featured)[0]}
                promoLoading={this.props.promotions.isLoading}
                promoErrMess={this.props.promotions.errMess}
                leader={this.props.leaders.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]}
                leaderLoading={this.props.leaders.isLoading}
                leaderErrMess={this.props.leaders.errMess}

            />

<Route path='/aboutus' component={() => <About leaders={this.props.leaders.leaders}
                            isLoading={this.props.leaders.isLoading}
                            errMess={this.props.leaders.errMess} />} />
```

Comment: I have made sure that all the props are matching properly.

Comment: Hard for us to tell you what's wrong with the other component if you don't link it :) If they're exactly the same, then there must be a prop difference -  you're not showing us how `Home` is invoked (or the other component) either

Answer (score 0):

Home Component works fine since it renders individual cards. Whereas for the below structure,

```
const leaders = props.leaders.map((leader) => {
return (
    <RenderLeader leader={leader} isLoading={props.isLoading}
        errMess={props.errMess} />
);
});
```

if props.leaders is empty, it cannot iterate and hence **RenderLeader will never get called**. Hence when props.isLoading is true, the props.leaders will be empty and the above arrow function will return nothing. And once the props.leaders is populated, the above function gets called, but props.isLoading will already be set to false.
That is why the loading icon or the error message was not displayed.

You can modify the calling as,

```
<div className="col-12">
       <Media list>
            <RenderLeaderList leaders={props.leaders} isLoading= 
                   {props.leadersLoading} errMess={props.leadersErrMess}/>
       </Media>
</div>
```

and create a new function called RenderLeaderList like;

```
function RenderLeaderList({leaders, isLoading, errMess})
{
      if(isLoading)
      {
        return(
         <Loading />
        );
      }
      else if(errMess)
      {
         return(
            <h4>{errMess}</h4>
         );
      }
      else{
         if(leaders!=null)
         {
            const leaders_map = leaders.map((leader) => {
            return(
                <div key={leader.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                    <RenderLeader leader={leader}/>
                </div>
            );
          });
         return (
            <div>
                {leaders_map}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

}
to make it work.
Hope it helps! :D